# WSS3.0 Workflow timer job overloading server?

Tags: workflow, wss-3.0

Everytime I enable the workflow timer job in central admin, our server cpu spikes to 100% and never drops. I have not added any new workflows, is there anyway to figure out which workflow could be causing the spike?

Comment: You can check the library/list size on which workflow is implemented.

Comment: well there are around 20 site collections each with a bunch of lists and a couple of those lists have a couple workflows attached to them. It's not something I implemented that all of a sudden started causing this. So I'm having trouble narrowing it down.

Answer (score 0):

Please try checking the log for workflow timer service. 
Refer [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/sharepoint2010general/thread/c486e634-743d-4b22-a6dd-8ebd924bc1e0) thread on msdn.

Comment: Hmm... checking the log while I turned on the workflow timer job did give me a direction, but still not sure which workflow it is in the log i got tons of these

<code>List item query elapsed time: 2970 milliseconds, Additional data (if available): Query HRESULT: 0 List internal name, flags, and URL: {4CFD257E-211F-4B87-A98F-0BB5441DB93D}, flags=0x0000000020c01000, URL="https://removed.com" Query XML: "<Query/>" SQL Query:</code>

Comment: Ok so figured out 4CFD257E-211F-4B87-A98F-0BB5441DB93D is my Task list and what site this is happening on, but my task list doesn't have any work flows running. So I guess its a workflow on another List that has some code to query the task list none stop. Anyone have idea more ideas to find out where this is getting called from?

Comment: Well you can open the site in SharePoint designer and check all the workflows on the site and try figuring out the task list associated with the workflow.

Comment: I don't think you can open workflows flows built with Visual studio in sharepoint designer? and there are quite a number of them.